# Use an ionic2 provider from a customly created class

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2

I don't know exactly how to formulate well this question, but basically, I have in my ionic2 app a file that look like this:

```
import { MyProvider } from '../providers/myProvider';

export class MyModel {

  constructor (public config: any) {}

  method1 () {
    console.log(this.config)
  }

  method2 () {
    // I want to use a method from MyProvider here, for example, it could look like the following:
    myProvider.alert(this.config.text)
  }

}
```

I want, from this `MyModel` class to be able to use functionalities from `MyProvider`.
Normally, from a provider, I would do the following:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { MyProvider } from '../providers/myProvider';

@Injectable()
export class AnotherProvider {

  constructor (public myProvider: MyProvider) {}

  value = "Some text"

  method1 () {
    myProvider.alert(this.value)
  }

}
```

But I also want to use `MyModel` like so:

```
newModel1 = new MyModel ({ text: "A bit of text" })
```

If I declare `public myProvider: MyProvider` in `MyModel`'s constructor, then when I create the new instance of `MyModel` I get a typescript error, because I'm missing one parameter (I'd need to pass myProvider as an argument).

I would like to combine the advantage of having a model with methods, that I can create using `new MyModel(someConf)`, and have the possibility to use other providers of my app easily from `MyModel`.
How can I do that?

Note: I don't think I can use `MyProvider`'s methods directly in `MyModel`, without passing the provider in `MyModel`'s constructor.

Answer (score 0):

remove this

```
constructor (**public config: any**) {}
```

public config: any

declare this inside constructor

then decalre your provider normally in your modal as

```
public yourProvider: YourMainProviderName
```

Comment: I think what you describe is just what I do in `AnotherProvider` in my question. No? It doesn't achieve my goal.